# Ubuntu 20.04.1 (host) and windows 10 (guest). No USB's detected on guest with virtualbox ( 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1)?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, usb, virtualbox

I installed extensions pack (6.1.10-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) and guest additions(though this is not required for getting USB's working across guests).
Shared folders, shared clipboard, webcam, audio (in and out) are working fine.
But usb's are not getting detected by virtual box. At the time of screenshot I have a USB pendrive pluggedin to the system.
[image]

Current USB settings use USB 2.0 -  but i tried 3.0 too and no luck.
Every USB Port on my system is USB 3.1 Gen 1 port (data transfer speeds up to 5 Gbps)
[image]

Any hints on how to fix this. Previous posts may not help much as I am thinking environment makes bit of difference. (I myself had USBs working across guests on earlier setups).

Comment: if this Q&A helped you or provides useful info.. please consider Up Voting the Q&A so it in turn helps others. I had to struggle a lot find the fix which turned out to be quite simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the current user to vboxusers group fixed the problem. The USB devices are now showing up on the windows 10 VM.
`sudo gpasswd -a yourusername vboxusers`

Reference - [How to Access USB from VirtualBox Guest OS](https://www.linuxbabe.com/virtualbox/access-usb-from-virtualbox-guest-os)

Comment: if this Q&A helped you or provides useful info.. please consider Up Voting the Q&A so it in turn helps others. I had to struggle a lot find the fix which turned out to be quite simple.

Comment: don't works vmbox 7 version

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I need to restart the linux host after adding vboxusers group.

Comment: don't works vmbox 7 version